# Impossible to write { } curly brackets on croatian keyboards on Atom text editor

Tags: atom-editor, brackets

I'm having trouble writing { } and [ ] brackets on Atom text editor.
My keyboard is setup on Croatian, I've tried to add a keyboard shortcut but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can unset key binding for <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+B</kbd> like this:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-alt-b': 'unset!'
```

Just find a key binding that you want to remove, copy it and set it's value to "unset!"

Here is my full mapping:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-alt-b': 'unset!'
  'ctrl-alt-f': 'unset!'

'.platform-win32 atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-alt-.': 'unset!'

'atom-workspace atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'ctrl-alt-f': 'unset!'

'.platform-win32, .platform-linux':
  'ctrl-alt-f': 'unset!'

'.platform-win32 atom-text-editor, .platform-linux atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-alt-q': 'unset!'
```

Comment: I have  the same issue with it on Hungarian keyboard, but alt-f [ and alt-b { I tried your solution but didn't work... Can you help me?

Comment: @TakácsZsolt I have edited my answer. I included my mappings. Have no idea why it doesn't work on Hungarian keyboard. Do you use Mac, Win or Linux? This can also bi a reason why. Hope that I have helped.

Also you may want to take a look at this: https://atom.io/packages/keyboard-localization

Comment: Ok, we can unset key bindings... But how to set them? I am having problem with curly brace (opening) and ok, I unset binding for alt+b, it's now doing nothing, but I must bind '{' now. You know how?

Comment: Try to remove the `unset` keyword. `Ctrl+Alt+B` should be default binding. Also it will be good to open a new question for this.

Comment: @tomislav.klisanic I have hungarian keyboard as well, but for me it worked like charm, so the above solution should work for Zsolt as well.

Answer (score 2):

After I unset above mentioned keybindings, I just figured out if you press <kbd>ALTGr</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> keys it would produce open and close curly braces, using hungarian keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

for MAC is:
shift + option + š -> {
shift + option + đ -> }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).